# Ruby on Rails: Why Isn't My Nested Form Working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have followed the RailsCast video into creating nested forms: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?autoplay=true

But for some reason it isn't saving.

When creating an email I am trying to create records in the recipients table, so that it can be recorded which groups and contacts the email was sent to. This works but I am also trying to save data to a column called "message" in this table, but for some reason the new record in the recipients table is made but the message is not saved in the table.

My models are:

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :account
    has_many :recipients
    has_many :contacts, through: :recipients, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :groups, through: :recipients, :dependent => :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipients
end
class Recipient < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to :email
   belongs_to :contact
   belongs_to :group

end
```

My `emails_controller` new and create methods are:

```
def new
    @email = Email.new
    @email.recipients.build
    @useraccounts = Useraccount.where(user_id: session[:user_id])
end

def create
    @email = Email.new(email_params)
    if @email.save
        redirect_to @email
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
private
def email_params
    params.require(:email).permit(:subject, :account_id, { contact_ids: [] }, { group_ids: [] }, recipient_attributes: [:message])
end
```

And my `_form.html.erb` is

```
<%= form_for @email do |f| %>

  <% if @email.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@email.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this email from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @email.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :account_id, "Send from account" %><br>
    <% @useraccounts.each do |useraccount| %>
        <%= f.radio_button :account_id, useraccount.account_id, :checked => false %>
        <%= f.label :account_id, useraccount.account.email, :value => "true"  %><br>
    <% end %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :subject %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :subject %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :contacts, "Send to Contacts:" %><br>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :contact_ids, Contact.where(user_id: session[:user_id]), :id, :firstname ,{ prompt: "firstname" } %>
  </p>

 <p>
    <%= f.label :groups, "Send to Groups:" %><br>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :group_ids, Group.where(user_id: session[:user_id]), :id, :name ,{ prompt: "name" } %>
  </p>

   <%= f.fields_for :recipients do |t| %>
    <%= t.label :message %>
    <%= t.text_field :message %>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

Can someone please help me work out why the `message` field is not being saved in the recipients table whilst a new row is being created in the table?

Comment: What does your create action look like?

Comment: @Iceman I've just added that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def new
    @email = Email.new
    @email.recipients.build
    @useraccounts = Useraccount.where(user_id: session[:user_id])
end

def create
    @email = Email.new(email_params)
    @email.recipients.build(email_params[:recipient_attributes])

    if @email.save
        redirect_to @email
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

You need to build your recipients in your create action as well. So when you perform save on @email the corresponding recipient will also get saved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though I'm afraid that didn't work